# How to convert some records ins SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with values like this:

```
## codel ##
1-829549-305-117
1-1196585-305-119
119.305.1983984.1 // this record
1-224594-305-121
1-1999987-305-121
122.306.113416.1 // this record
1-158059-305-122
1-1083888-305-126
```

Code for convert 119.305.1983984.1 to 1.1983984.305.119 is :

```
DECLARE @myvar varchar(20);  
SET @myvar = '119.305.1983984.1';  

SELECT 
    CONCAT(PARSENAME(@myvar, 1), '-',
           PARSENAME(@myvar, 2), '-',
           PARSENAME(@myvar, 3), '-',
           PARSENAME(@myvar, 4))
```

The output should be:

```
## codel ##
1-829549-305-117
1-1196585-305-119
1-1983984-305-119 // this record has changed
1-224594-305-121
1-1999987-305-121
1-113416-306-122 // this record has changed
1-158059-305-122
```

Comment: So what is the actual issue?

Comment: what is the version of the sql server you are using?

Comment: Do you want to do the same thing with the ones with dashes `-`?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the most important thing when asking a question; asking a question. What is yours?

Comment: At a guess, *maybe*, they want to switch the positions of the elements when the value ends with `'1'`, rather than begins with and change the `.`'s to `-`? `CONVERT` is definitely the wrong word here though.

Comment: He's using `SQL Sever 2012` or newer since he uses `CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this code

```
 SELECT [Codel],
case WHEN  (CHARINDEX('.',[Codel]) > 0) then 

    CONCAT(PARSENAME([Codel], 1), '-',
           PARSENAME([Codel], 2), '-',
           PARSENAME([Codel], 3), '-',
           PARSENAME([Codel], 4))  
           else [Codel] end
            true_template

  FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[CodelTbl]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the `-` with `.`, because `PARSENAME()` works only with `'.'`, not `'-'`

```
WITH TBL AS
(
  SELECT       '1-829549-305-117' Str
  UNION SELECT '1-1196585-305-119'
  UNION SELECT '119.305.1983984.1' 
  UNION SELECT '1-224594-305-121'
  UNION SELECT '1-1999987-305-121'
  UNION SELECT '122.306.113416.1' 
  UNION SELECT '1-158059-305-122'
  UNION SELECT '1-1083888-305-126'
),
CTE AS
(
  SELECT Str,
         CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Str) > 0 THEN
                   Str
              ELSE REPLACE(Str, '-', '.')
         END Str1
         ,
         CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Str) > 0 THEN '.' ELSE '-' END Sep
  FROM TBL
)
SELECT Str,
       CONCAT(PARSENAME(Str1,1), Sep,
              PARSENAME(Str1,2), Sep,
              PARSENAME(Str1,3), Sep,
              PARSENAME(Str1,4)
              ) Result

FROM CTE;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|        Str        |      Result       |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1-1083888-305-126 | 126-305-1083888-1 |
| 1-1196585-305-119 | 119-305-1196585-1 |
| 1-158059-305-122  | 122-305-158059-1  |
| 119.305.1983984.1 | 1.1983984.305.119 |
| 1-1999987-305-121 | 121-305-1999987-1 |
| 122.306.113416.1  | 1.113416.306.122  |
| 1-224594-305-121  | 121-305-224594-1  |
| 1-829549-305-117  | 117-305-829549-1  |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=33d3f4c45592e7fb76eb5615ae3b4c0b)**

---

If you have SQL Server 2017, then you can use **[`CONCAT_WS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** as

```
SELECT Str,
       CONCAT_WS(Sep, 
              PARSENAME(Str1,1), 
              PARSENAME(Str1,2), 
              PARSENAME(Str1,3), 
              PARSENAME(Str1,4)
              ) Result

FROM CTE;
```

---

If you want the separator to be always `'-'`then no need to `Sep`, just directly `'-'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can split your string based on "." and use the values separately:

```
create table #temp (rn int identity(1,1), num int)

Declare @products varchar(200) = '119.305.1983984.1'
Declare @individual varchar(20) = null

WHILE LEN(@products) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%.%', @products) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@products,
                                    0,
                                    PATINDEX('%.%', @products))
        insert into #temp
        SELECT @individual

        SET @products = SUBSTRING(@products,
                                  LEN(@individual + '.') + 1,
                                  LEN(@products))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = @products
        SET @products = NULL

        insert into #temp
        SELECT @individual
    END
END
select * from #temp
```

Ref: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: I don't really recommend a `WHILE` loop. There are plenty better set based solutions for splitting data in SQL Server. The question you've linked actually has far more upvotes on the answer using `PARSENAME`; which the OP is making (good?) use of.